# Inconsistent scope of 'this' in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript all functions are objects. So how come when I use 'this' like so:

```
var myObj = function() {
    doSomething: function() {
        alert('msg');
    }

    myFunc2: function () {
        this.doSomething(); //'this' doesn't equal myFunc2, it's myObj
    }
}
```

'this' refers to myObj and not myFunc2? Javascript has function scope, 'this' is being used in myFunc2 so it should refer to myFunc2.

Why is this not the case? This language seems very inconsistent at times.

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You've got a function with two nested functions, but nothing ever calls them.

Comment: This isn't even valid javascript? Did you mean for myObj to be an object and not a function?

Comment: `this` **never** refers to the function itself unless **explicitly** set so. How `this` works isn't that difficult, I suggest to read an article about it.

Comment: Felix Kling: The fact that you and Pointy have left comments indicating the first 3 answers are incorrect or incomplete makes me think `this` isn't as straight forward as you assert.

Comment: Could be. Maybe I'm exposed to it for too long. The tl;dr version is: The value of `this` depends on how the function is **called**. There are four ways to call a function: as function, object method, as constructor (`new`) and `.call` / `.apply`. Exceptions: Bound functions (`.bind`) have a fixed `this` value. Arrow functions have "lexical" `this`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . Personally I don't find this too complicated :P

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have "function scope", what you are experimenting the how the `this` works in JavaScript.

The `this` keyword always reference the object that is calling the function, in this case, `myObj`.

Check this chapter from the **You Don't Know JS** book series to learn more about how `this` works in JavaScript:

[You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)

Comment: Of course JavaScript has function scope.

Comment: The "function scope" from JavaScript only affects hoisting, not `this`.

Comment: Sure, function scope doesn't have much to do with `this`, but that doesn't mean JavaScript does not have function scope.

Comment: *"The `this` keyword always reference the object that is calling the function"* I'm sure you know how it works, but that is strangely phrased and not very complete.